# Sum of the digits of a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that the sum of the digits of a perfect square can't be 2, 3, 5
>   , 6, or 8.

I'm completely stumped on this one, how would I go about proving it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sum of the digits of a number is invariant mod $9$. So this is the same as asking what are and what are not the squares mod $9$?

Let's consider: the squares mod $9$ are $1,4, 7$ (coming from $1,2,4$). The complement of these are $2,3,5,6,8$, which are exactly the parts from your question. These are the numbers which do not appear as squares mod $9$, and thus do not appear as sums of digits of squares.

Comment: In your first sentence, are you trying to say that the sum of the digits of a base 10 integer is always equal to the modulo 9 value of that integer?   For example the base 10 number 3751 converted to base 9 is 5127.  The sum 3+7+5+1 = 16.   The mod9 of 5127 is simply its LSD, since the number is in base 9, so 5127 mod9 = 7.

The problem is that 16 != 7.   Did you mean to say that "the sum of the decimal digits summed recursively until reduced to a single digit"?

Answer (score -1):

If your square number had the sum of digits equal to 3 or 6, then it must be a multiple of 3. But a square that is a multiple of 3 must be a multiple of 9. Therefore the sum of its digits must be a multiple of 9. 3 or 6 are not multiples of 9.

Therefore 3 and 6 are impossible.

Comment: This is not a complete answer -1